# React/css Flexbox with stylable rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

i have a specific use case, and i am not sure what component or technology i can use for that.

I have a set of items in a wrapped flexbox:

> xxx|xxxxxxxx|xx|xxxxxxxxx| 
>   x|xxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxx| 
>   xxxxx|xxxxxxxxxx|XXXX|xxxx 
>   xxxx|xxxxx|xxxxxxxxx

The items have different widths, but fixed heights. And their should be wrapped, so that there is no horizontal overflow. And there is alway one "active" item, which has a diffent style.

For now flexbox works perfecly fine for me. Here's a demo:

```css
.wpr {
  width: 150px;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 2px;
}
span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #111;
}
.special {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">
  <span>xxx</span>
  <span>xxxxxx</span>
  <span>xxx</span>
  <span>xxxxx</span>
  <span>xxx</span>
  <span>xxxxx</span>
  <span class="special">XXX</span>
  <span>xx</span>
  <span>xxxxxxxx</span>
  <span>xx</span>
</div>
```

But now i want to also highlight the complete row of the active item. The problem is, that i dont what items are in which row, because flexbox ist handling that.

For example:

> xxx|xxxxxxxx|xx|xxxxxxxxx| 
>   x|xxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxx| 
>   **xxxxx|xxxxxxxxxx|XXXX|xxxx** 
>
>   xxxx|xxxxx|xxxxxxxxx

Just to see also in which row the active item is.

I am using React and Flexbox. But im not sure if thats possible with flexbox.

I could render every single item into a hidden DOM element to get its size and calculate the row-number by myself, but this is very hacky....

Do you know a trick to do that? Or maybe a different layout system, which is able to do that?

Edit: Examplecode:

```
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap", maxWidth: "960px" }}>
      {this.state.myItems.map((w, i) => (
        <div className={`${i !== this.state.activeIndex ? "playerword" : "playerword-active"}`} style={{ marginTop: "15px", fontSize: "1.3em", cursor: "pointer" }}>
          <div className="olBack" style={{ padding: "3px" }}>
            {w[0]}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
```

-Alexander

Comment: Please add some code so we can reproduce the question. Do you know what other items are in the row next to your active item?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that CSS can't do this

Comment: I dont have to use flexbox. I also could use something else instead. But i dont know what.. :/

Comment: There is no CSS that will let you style a specific *row* (regardless of layout method) unless the row is defined as a separate element. That is not the case here. You need Javascript.